# Wifi but no internet - Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Octos and Android 7.1.2.  I have been able to connect to the internet in the past, but currently when it connects to the wifi it does not connect to the internet.

I have tried:

- rebooting the router
- turning wifi on/off on the phone
- turning wifi on/off on the router (this works for the Samsung S3 using Android 4)
- resetting network settings on the phone
- using a manual IP address on the phone

I'm considering installing a new Octos firmware.

I have the same problem with a Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.

Comment: I have the same problem with my new Moto G6 phone running the latest Android.  I can only get internet if I switch from the 2.4 ghz to 5 ghz network (and back again) on an approximately daily basis.